# How to parse xml file and to create objects to add in array for tableview in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, uitableview

I muste parse an XML file that contains some courses.
Foreach course I must create an object and at the end to the tag  I must add in array, so I can create tableview by array of objects. But I dont't be able to determine the end of course to add to the array. How to be able to do?

XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<courses>
    <course>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>Introduzione al Java</title>
        <description>Corso base java, definizione di classe, oggetti ecc</description>
        <creation_date>2014-01-19 22:52:12</creation_date>
        <teachers>
            <teacher>Paolo</teacher>
            <teacher>Fabio</teacher>
        </teachers>
    </course>
    <course>
        <id>2</id>
        <title>Concetti Avanzati Java</title>
        <description>Corso avanzato java, prove pratiche su sistemi complessi</description>
        <creation_date>2014-02-22 20:52:12</creation_date>
        <teachers>
            <teacher>Giorgio Magherini</teacher>
        </teachers>
    </course>
    <course>
        <id>3</id>
        <title>Concetti Avanzati PHP</title>
        <description>Corso PHP avanzato, prove di verifica su siti online</description>
        <creation_date>2013-01-19 22:52:12</creation_date>
        <teachers>
            <teacher>Giorgio</teacher>
        </teachers>
    </course>
</courses>
```

I use NSXMLParserDelegate and the methods used are:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
   attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"courses"]) {
        arrayCorsiDisponibili = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];// I allocate and init arrayCourseAvaiable
         self.stringaAppoggio = @"courses";
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"course"]){

        CourseAvailable *corsoDisponibile = [[CourseAvailable alloc]init]; //I allocate and init object
        self.courseAvailableAppoggio = corsoDisponibile;
        self.stringaAppoggio = @"course";
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"id"]){

    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]){

    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"description"]) {

        self.stringaAppoggio = @"description";
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"creation_date"]) {

        self.stringaAppoggio = @"creation_date";
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"teacher"]) {
         self.stringaAppoggio = @"teacher";
    }
}
```

And

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if ([self.stringaAppoggio isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
        return;
    }
    if ([self.stringaAppoggio isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        return;
    }
    else if ([self.stringaAppoggio isEqualToString:@"courses"])
    {
        return;
    }
    else if ([self.stringaAppoggio isEqualToString:@"course"])
    {
        return;
    }
    else if ([self.stringaAppoggio isEqualToString:@"id"])
    {
        self.courseAvailableAppoggio.idCorso = (NSNumber *)string;
        return;
    }
    else if([self.stringaAppoggio isEqualToString:@"title"])
    {
        self.courseAvailableAppoggio.titolo = string;
        return;
    }
    else if([self.stringaAppoggio isEqualToString:@"description"])
    {
        self.courseAvailableAppoggio.descrizione = string;
        return;
    }
    else if([self.stringaAppoggio isEqualToString:@"creation_date"])
    {
        self.courseAvailableAppoggio.dataCreazione = string;
        return;
    }
    else if([self.stringaAppoggio isEqualToString:@"teacher"])
    {
        [self.courseAvailableAppoggio.insegnante addObject:string];
        return;
    }
    [arrayCorsiDisponibili addObject:self.courseAvailableAppoggio];
}
```

How to be able to determine the end  to add object in array?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check for the tags you're interested in in

```
– parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:
```

method.

Answer (score 1):

I used this lib. with enumerate in block https://github.com/ZaBlanc/RaptureXML

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following links which have detail implementation of XML parsing.
 [link1](http://ipad.about.com/od/iPad-App-Dev/a/How-To-Parse-Xml-Files-In-X) and
[link2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project).